# how to insert text with multiple lines in string node in GN?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to display text with several lines in GN.

Especially my text is in the text editor, i copy paste it into the string node and i got...one line.

Is there a trick to insert more lines?
What am i missing?

[image]

Comment: I'm not at a Blender computer right now, but what actually happens when you type "\n" for a line break? ...you would need a special character here. somehow. ...there is a node for this special char, as far as i remember.

Comment: then i got this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll0dR.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve the desired result by using each line as a separate string input, and linking them together with a `Special Character` as a *Delimiter*:

[image]

Another solution would be to write everything in one line, and set the width of the text field with *Max Width*. This would create automatic line breaks.

---

If you really want to write everything in a string value, you could use any character as a separator, and replace it with a *Special Character*:

[image]

Comment: That’s what I didn’t want to do because I am lazy…I hoped for a solution with one string node

Comment: @Chris I understand, you could of course replace any character with the *Special Character* (see updated answer)

Comment: @Chris I have now looked at the source code: Apparently there really is no other way, unfortunately, because the line break really cannot be interpreted from the text. This is probably exactly why the `Special Character` node exists.

Comment: that's totally ok for me!! thanks!

Comment: Is there roadmap for integration of multi-line input ? Currently, there is only text-editor editor, but it would be nice to have this feature in nodetree, or any developer wanting this ui feature to make addon that don't rely on the current text-editor.

Comment: I use the solution from the second image, One thing I also do is using `\n` for Line Break and `\t` for Tab, cause I'm hoping those will work someday in the future and they make the most sense.